# Data Source Library error: the web cannot be opened

Tags: sharepoint-designer, wss-3.0, error, data-view-web-part

Version of sharepoint: WSS 3.0

I opened a site, Home, in SharePoint Designer 2007. When I tried to insert the data view, it only show the greyed "+ Current Site".

When I clicked "Connect to another library" to try to add the "Home" content,

> A collection can be added only once for each Web site

is prompted.

When I open the *subsite* of "Home" and try to add the library of "Home", "The web 'HOME.URL' cannot be opened" is poped up.

The Data Source Library also greyed out when I add the library of the subsite in "Home".

But everything is fine, for opening the library of *subsite* in another *subsite*.

Please kindly teach me what to do. Thank you!